# How to save list of nested two separate objects

Tags: json, spring-boot

How to write model class and establish relation between classes. To save and update the below the JSON using spring boot.

**inputJSON**

```
 {
  "modelName": "",
  "modelDescription": "",
  "recordStatus": true,
  "details": [
    {
      "tMemberDetail": {
        "param1": "",
        "pn": {
          "param1": "",
          "param2": ""
        },
        "an": {
          "param1": "",
          "param2": ""
        },
        "p": {
          "h": {
            "param1": "",
            "param2": ""
          },
          "v": {
            "param1": "",
            "param2": ""
          },
          "r": {
            "param1": "",
            "param2": ""
          }
        },
        "t": {
          "param1": ""
        }
      },
      "mattributes": {
        "param1": "",
        "SP": {
          "param1": "",
          "param2": ""
        },
        "EP": {
          "param1": "",
          "param2": ""
        },
        "F": {
          "Required": false,
          "FT": "",
          "G": {
            "param1": ""
          },
          "FP": {
            "param1": "",
            "param2": ""
          },
          "Pmr": {
            "Required": false,
            "Details": {
              "param1": "",
              "param2": ""
            }
          },
          "Pnt": {
            "Required": false,
            "Details": {
              "param1": "",
              "param2": ""
            }
          },
          "ASS": {
            "Required": false,
            "Details": {
              "param1": ""
            }
          },
          "NPA": {
            "Required": false,
            "Details": {
              "param1": "",
              "param2": ""
            }
          }
        },
        "Start": {
          "param1": "",
          "Loads": {
            "param1": ""
          }
        },
        "End": {
          "param1": "",
          "Loads": {
            "param1": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to achieve by writing model class like below

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Model extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long modelId;
    private String modelName;
    private String modelDescription;
    private RecordStatus recordStatus=RecordStatus.ACTIVE;  
}

@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TModel extends Model implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7331603514610649855L;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TMember > tMembers ;

}

@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TMember implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7331603514610649855L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long tMemberId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , orphanRemoval = true)
    private TMemberDetail tMemberDetail;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , orphanRemoval = true)
    private MemberAttribute memberAttributes;

}
```

The problem I am facing here is that every time I update call child objects, auto incremental id's are incremented by 1.

If I call `get` service from another application I get only
modelName, modelDescription, recordStatus but not the entire data.